# Linear Regression in Python following Andrew ng video

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression

I came across andrew Ng's course on youtube and watched the following [video](https://youtu.be/KndtpX9Hl6I?t=2m3s) (2min03)

I tried to implement the following function [image] to plot it afterwards has he shows in his slides, but it seems that I only get a slope. Moreover, I  have tried to plot the theta0 and theta1 against JList as a mesh plot I keep getting an an erroneous plot, any help on how to get the same plot as in his video is welcome

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from fractions import Fraction
from matplotlib import cm


theta0=[]
theta1=[]
JList=[]

csv=np.genfromtxt('ex1.data', delimiter=",")
x=csv[:,0]
y=csv[:,1]

for a in np.arange(-50,50,1):
     for b in np.arange(1,10,1):
          theta0.append(a)
          theta1.append(b)

          result=0
          for c in range(len(x)):
               sum=float(a+(b*x[c])-(y[c]))
               np.power(sum,2)          
               result+=float(sum)
          Jt=0
          Jt=Fraction(1,2*len(x))
          Jt=Jt*result
          JList.append(int(Jt))
 fig = plt.figure()
 ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
 X, Y = np.meshgrid(theta1, theta0)
 surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, JList, cmap=cm.coolwarm,
                   linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
 plt.show()
```

This is a sample of ex1.data

```
6.1101,17.592
5.5277,9.1302
8.5186,13.662
7.0032,11.854
5.8598,6.8233
8.3829,11.886
7.4764,4.3483
8.5781,12
6.4862,6.5987
5.0546,3.8166
5.7107,3.2522
14.164,15.505
5.734,3.1551
8.4084,7.2258
5.6407,0.71618
5.3794,3.5129
6.3654,5.3048
5.1301,0.56077
6.4296,3.6518
7.0708,5.3893
6.1891,3.1386
20.27,21.767
5.4901,4.263
6.3261,5.1875
5.5649,3.0825
18.945,22.638
12.828,13.501
10.957,7.0467
13.176,14.692
22.203,24.147
5.2524,-1.22
6.5894,5.9966
9.2482,12.134
5.8918,1.8495
8.2111,6.5426
7.9334,4.5623
8.0959,4.1164
5.6063,3.3928
12.836,10.117
6.3534,5.4974
5.4069,0.55657
```

I believe there is an error in the python code to compute [image] and there is no error, this is what it plots [image: J(theta1,theta0)] which I doubt is what it's meant to show.

Comment: can you provide the `ex1.data`? and what error are you getting?

Comment: @RafaelBarros I have added ex1.data and an example of the figure that I get.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it was linear was due to my mistake `np.power(sum,2)` 
which should be modified in `sum=np.power(sum,2)`.